# Reset radio selection from <label> click

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a touchscreen friendly dropdown with side menu lists that come out. I used a hidden radio button method to provide functionality of opening each menu with touches by using labels to control the radio button.

I want people to be able to touch again on a selected item to collapse it back in. It can't be check boxes, because the side menus come out on the same area next to the previous menu, so I need my radio buttons to be able to deselect what is currently selected.

I found this for making radio buttons deselectable and it works:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.querySelectorAll("INPUT[type='radio']").forEach(function(rd){rd.addEventListener("mousedown",
    function(){
        if (this.checked) {this.onclick=function(){this.checked=false}} else{this.onclick=null}
    })})}
```

I needed to modify as this I need the listener on the labels that are immediately after the radio button elements (since the radio buttons are hidden and controlled through the label). So I tried doing this to it:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.querySelectorAll('ul li > input + label').forEach(function(rd){rd.addEventListener("mousedown",
    function(){
        if (this.previousElementSibling.checked) {this.onclick=function(){this.previousElementSibling.checked=false}} else{this.onclick=null}
    })})}
```

I feel like it should be working, but it does not. I was worried I wasn't able to get the previousElementSibling of a label, but this worked just fine to show me the status I am trying to modify:

```
function gettest() {
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.querySelector('ul li > input + label').previousElementSibling.checked
}
```

Here is the HTML for the expanding menu made of nested lists:

```
<nav id="lcn-dropdown">
    <input type="checkbox" id="main-drop">
    <label for="main-drop" id="toggle-main">&dtrif;</label>
    <ul id="main-list">
    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="1-1-radio" name="1-menu">
    <label for="1-1-radio" class="sub-toggle">&nbsp; A00-A08 &rtrif;</label>
                                <ul class="side-from-1">
                                <li><a href ="#"> A00 ALIS &rtrif;</a>
                                                        <!--<ul class="side-from-1">
                                                        <li><a href ="#" class="third"> A00100 Test</a></li>
                                                        <li>              <a href ="#"> XXXXXX</a></li>
                                                        <li> <a href ="#" class="last"> XXXXXX</a></li>
                                                        </ul>-->
                                </li>
                                <li><a href ="#"> A01 Documentation &rtrif;</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#"> A03 Servicing &rtrif;</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#"> A05 General &rtrif;</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#"> A07 Testing &rtrif;</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#" class="last"> A08 Testing &rtrif;</a></li>
                                </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The top level checkbox works just fine as that dropdown space is always there. The issue is only the radio button one as I want the expected functionality of collapsing by reclicking the selected item, but cannot allow multiple items selected to expand into the same area.

Comment: If you're going to go down the java script route, I'd ditch the radio buttons completely and just add/remove a CSS class via javascript. The only reason to use radio buttons/check boxes is to handle it all via CSS.

Comment: I like that it is functional with only CSS, and have it practically completely done if a radio button can be unclickable. I'm literally a small function away from the whole thing working perfect, but thank you for taking the time to make a suggestion.

Comment: The thing is though, I don't know that a radio button is unclickable from the label. It seems possible with an event handler on the button, but not the label. Radio buttons, by design, are not meant to be unclickable, so you're fighting against that for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly but I think I've got it.

The click event for the radio button fires when the label is clicked. Use the mousedown of the label to capture the current state of the radio button. Then in the event handler for the radio button, check this state and untoggle as required.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelectorAll('ul li > input + label').forEach(function(rd) {
    rd.addEventListener("mousedown",
      function() {
        //store if we need to toggle as a data attribute on the radio button
        this.previousElementSibling.dataset.uncheck = this.previousElementSibling.checked;
      });
  });


  document.querySelectorAll('ul li > input[type=radio]').forEach(function(rd) {
      rd.addEventListener("click",  function() {          
          var tog = this.checked && this.dataset.uncheck === "true";
          console.log(this);
          //Check the data attribute   
          if (tog == true) {
            this.checked = false;
          }
        });
      });
  };
```

```html
<nav id="lcn-dropdown">
  <input type="checkbox" id="main-drop">
  <label for="main-drop" id="toggle-main">&dtrif;</label>
  <ul id="main-list">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="1-1-radio" name="1-menu">
      <label for="1-1-radio" class="sub-toggle">&nbsp; A00-A08 &rtrif;</label>
      <ul class="side-from-1">
        <li><a href="#"> A00 ALIS &rtrif;</a>
          <!--<ul class="side-from-1">
                                                        <li><a href ="#" class="third"> A00100 Test</a></li>
                                                        <li>              <a href ="#"> XXXXXX</a></li>
                                                        <li> <a href ="#" class="last"> XXXXXX</a></li>
                                                        </ul>-->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> A01 Documentation &rtrif;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> A03 Servicing &rtrif;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> A05 General &rtrif;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> A07 Testing &rtrif;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="last"> A08 Testing &rtrif;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am happy you looked through a way to make it work, but I kind of covered the idea of getting the element by id as working fine, but I am trying to do it with just that top part selecting all of the labels. Maybe I need to update the question to make it more focused on getting the selector to work. Any ideas why it wouldn't work to get that array of the labels and then get the status of the previous element since it is always the radio input element?

Comment: It's due to the way the label, radio button and mouse events interact. You effectively need two event handlers to do this from my experiments.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm reading through some more and I am curious what is happening with the whole dataset thing. OH okay so I at least see that you provided the important info that "click" for the radio fires from a label click TY for that! Will an setter of this.checked really change the radio element through using the label element?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the replacing the id selector with the actual selector you want to use. For more about the dataset read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes  . I'm using that to capture the status of the radio button on mouse down, i.e before it changes, which happens when the click is complete.

Comment: Sorry I havent just tried it yet, but isn't the this.checked referencing a label element?

Comment: Nope, it's referencing the radio button, we have an event handler for the label and an event handler for the radio button. The handler for the radio button also fires off the label. You can see this where I log the element with `console.log(this)`

Comment: I've also just fixed a copy and paste error, accidentally nested an event handler for the radio button.

Comment: I tried it in firefox with console view. It didn't work and threw for an extra curly brace. I deleted the last one with the semicolon. No error now, but it did not do anything or output anything to console either.

Comment: Is that running with "Run Code Snippet" above, or after moving the code to your environment?

Comment: OH MY LORD thank you so much! I realized that I needed the top part too. I thought you kept that in there just as reference to what I presented.

Thanks for mentioning the snippet thing. It ran and that made me realize the script being both parts. Sorry, I am new to posting on here.

Works like a dream!

Comment: See if I am interpreting this correctly after reading a bit. You have made mousedown on a label save the checked state to a data attribute in the radio input element. The click for radio immediately fires and compares the data attribute to the current radio state to force an "uncheck if checked" behavior?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it.